# CDI and HK2 Not working together

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi, hk2

I am not sure whether I understood the exact way of how these two does the injection using @Inject,but I recently developed an app where during the first phase of development I used Dependency Injection using @inject of HK2 and binded the resources using abstract binder,it worked fine.Then I wanted to inject one more value. I needed to inject a basic String values using @Inject and the value for this was got form a method annotated with @Produces.But when I do that I get this error.

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=String
```

I read in many places and many suggest CDI and HK2 have some issues working together.I am not able to resolve the issue.

When I try the above scenario in two different standalone programs they run fine.But when I integrate them I get the above error message.

This is what I found in java's jira:
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20597

My example is:

```
public ClassA{
  @Inject
      ClassBInter b;
  }
```

I binded the class b in the abstract binder

```
new AbstractBinder(){
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            //Binding the implementation to the interface
            bind(ClassBImpl.class).to(ClassBInter.class);
          }
   }
```

this worked fine.

but when I tried the below concept of adding an @Inject to a String in the same system,it crashes with the above exception

```
  public ClassC{

         @Inject
         String name;
   }
```

Producer Class

```
    public ProducerClass{

      @Produces
      public String getName(){
            return "henry Ford";
       }
     }
```

Comment: What version of GlassFish are you using?

Answer (score 1):

String injection is generally not supported, across the board.  You can use qualifiers, which should help with resolution.

Do you have a `beans.xml` file in your deployment?

Comment: I tried using Qualifiers and yes I have beans.xml ,but somehow I can be able to resolve this issue.I read somewhere in stackoverflow,that we should make HK2 work in harmony with CDI. Both work fine separately but when I integarte HK2 is throwing UnsatisfiedDependencyException for an injection which is resolved by CDI @Qualifer and Produces